# 2018 Moderator Election Notice - Timezones

Tags: discussion, election

Next week, on September 17th, [Server Fault will be hosting an election](https://serverfault.com/election/6). The election will be for 2 new moderators.

More importantly, though, when we had polled the mod team about whether a new moderator election would be needed, there was a recurring theme amongst the responses - we have a lot of weight on the US timezones but not so much in the Europe timezones.

This post is meant as a call to attention - we're hoping to encourage potential strong moderator candidates who are in European timezones to add extra consideration to throwing their hat in the ring. Note that there's no means (nor intent) to mechanically enforce this - the voting process itself will run the same regardless of the makeup of the candidate pool.

Comment: To whom it may concern: I'm in Europe and resigning. Unless somebody gets elected that will leave Sven as the only [moderator coverage](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators) in the CET timezone.

Comment: It should be stated as active hour, not timezone restriction, as I got strange workshift, and usually Iam active when european folk are around.

Comment: @HBruijn resigning? Well, that's no fun. Though I haven't been too active in the past few months (years?) either.